# Android : Set scroll view position to start at 80% from top of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to achieve something like this :

```
 -  |-------------------|<-------Phone screen
 |  ||-----------------||
 |  ||                 ||
80% ||                 ||
 |  ||                 ||
 |  ||                 |<--------Image View  (fills screen, background)
 -  |||---------------|||
 |  |||               |||
20% |||               |<---------Scroll View (starts after 80% of parent view)
 |  ||-----------------||
 -  |-------------------|
```

The ImageView has an image which fills the background and the scrollView starts after 80% of the height. Can somebody help me out on how to achieve this for all device sizes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `layout_weight`

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2">

        </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: shem, thank you. But as I commented to jboi's answer, wouldnt this split the layout into 2 halves ? 80% is which is the image and 20% of which is the scroll view ? I wanted the imageview to be background and the scroll view to be above the image view.

Answer (score 1):

You need a LinearLayout, `android:orientation="vertical"`.

Then add the two views (`ImageView` and `ScrollView`) with `android:layout_weight="80"` for the `ImageView` and `android:layout_weight="20"` for the `ScrollView`.

Both must have `android:layout_height="0dip"` to be sure, that only the weight counts.

The XML code looks like this (I've used a second ImageView instead of ScrollView to show the result in blue and red)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:src="#FF0000FF" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:src="#FFFF0000" />
```

EDIT: To fill the background with an image you have two ways:

- Simple set `android:backround="<your drawable resoure>"` of the `LinearLayout`. The only thing you might loose, is the possibility to center and resize the drawable within the background. An ImageView has more possibilities at this point.
- Therefore the second way is to use a `FrameLayout`. It's leightweight and basically does no positioning at all. Just puts all elements above each other. The XML looks like this:

  ```
      <!-- This is your fixed view, e.g. with header information -->
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dip"
          android:layout_weight="80"
          android:src="@android:color/transparent" />

      <!--  This would be your scroll view, e.g. for detail information -->
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dip"
          android:layout_weight="20"
          android:src="#FFFF0000" />
  ```

Comment: jboi, thank you. But wouldnt this split the layout into 2 halves ? 80% is which is the image and 20% of which is the scroll view ? I wanted the imageview to be background and the scroll view to be above the image view.

Comment: @paypalcomp. I've overseen that part. The easiest way to achieve a background image is to use the `android:background="<your image resource>"` of a LinearLayout.